# Scala which data structure is most efficient for my intended operations?

Tags: scala, arraybuffer, listbuffer

I am running a dynamic programming function where I carry a list of strings throughout the process.

Over time, I append new strings to the end of this list, and occasionally I may remove the last element. Right now I am currently using a mutable ListBuffer, doing `+=` for the appends and `.trimEnd(1)` for the removals.

Once my dynamic programming procedure is done, I need to efficiently be able to access each element of that list/sequence/etc, and in order (the first item I inserted will be first accessed, whereas last item I inserted will be the last accessed).

I've also tried ArrayBuffers but they both seem too slow. I am trying to speed this process up and I am wondering if I am using a data structure that has O(n) operations when there may be something that has O(1) time operations for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple singly linked list will provide O(1) for the append/discard portions of what you describe. Worst case, if you need to reverse the list at the end before processing, that would be an O(n) operation paid once.

Note that if you go down this road, during the accumulation phase "first" and "last" will be reversed (you will prepend items and drop the first item by getting the tail of the list).

Comment: Is there a built in datatype for this?

Comment: scala.collection.immutable.List - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Comment: Depending on what your post processing involves you should look at foldLeft, if it can be phrased as an accumulation step it would provide you the ordering you want pretty naturally.

Comment: This seems to be immutable, though. Or am I misunderstanding what is actually immutable? I need to be able to dynamically insert and remove items (my initial list will be empty)

Comment: yup, you don't need to mutate the list, just replace the reference with `myList = myList.tail` to drop an item, or `myList = newItem :: myList` to prepend a new item

Comment: What would it mean then to mutate the list, if that does not count as mutating?

Comment: No, it changes which list your reference points to. List is a recursive structure, it is formed by a `sealed trait List` with 2 implementations, the first is `case object Nil` representing the empty list, the second is `case class Cons(head: A, tail: List[A])` representing a List item in head and "the rest of the list" in tail. Prepending to such a list is a question of creating a new Cons with the new item as head and the old list as tail.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your earlier comment. Mutation in a List would be, for example, removing an item which was in the middle of the list without making a copy of all the items before it in the list. The immutability means that you can't change the value of head or the item referenced by tail. Your reference to the structure can be a var. Note that mutability is often unnecessary and can be problematic. I suggest doing some reading into functional programming and referential transparency you may find those topics of interest.